# Linked server and promotion of distributed transaction

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, linked-server

Background - Main server is Microsoft SQL Server 2019 and linked server is PostgreSQL 15.

Main reason for the linking is the duplication of records.

All other DML operations are good from SQL Server to Postgres.

Enable Promotion of Distributed Transaction is **False**.

(EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=..., @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'false')

But all operations in SQL Server **trigger** throw error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRESQL" was unable to begin a distributed transaction

...although promotion is set to *false*.

Why does SQL Server continue to promote this transaction despite the option?

Comment: Are you only calling a remote stored procedure or are you using other DML?

Comment: In the trigger I use only an insert - insert into postgres ... select ... from inserted;

Comment: That's not an remote procedure. I'd suggest you fix your DTC setup instead of trying to bypass it.

Comment: thx. But if I use a remote postgres procedure instead of the insert - will I be able to bypass distributed transaction?

Comment: Depends, since this is executed inside a trigger (which is already a poor idea) then most likely not.